# Magento2 Create Error

Tags: magento2.3, debugging

I don't know why, when I click save post it will return an error

[image]

Please help me!

Comment: what you want to and what you created.Please explain more...

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first thing is to get more information about the error, you can/should check var/log files (exception.log and system.log), also, be sure you have magento set to developer mode. Another thing I usually do while developing is to edit the file: **app/bootstrap.php** and uncomment the line: **ini_set('display_errors', 1);** (you don't want this enabled on a production site)